# Partially load data from files via File API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, partial, hybrid-mobile-app, fileapi

With [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) it is possible load data from local files into the browser memory via Javascript. I'm accessing huge files (200MB and bigger) on a system that is low in available RAM (webapp on an mobile device). How can I use the W3C [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) (or [Cordovas File Api](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) as a fallback) to partially load data (e.g. by specifying a byte range) from files?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [File.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice). Notice that `File` inherits from `Blob` and thereby receives its `slice()` method.

```
var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

Source of this information is [HTML5Rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files). A full example can be found there.